# How to implement equals() and hashcode() methods in BaseEntity of JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, equals, hashcode, tostring

I have a `BaseEntity` class which is a superclass of all JPA entities in my application.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3307436748176180347L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    protected long id;


    @Version
    @Column(name="VERSION", nullable=false, updatable=false, unique=false)
    protected long version;
}
```

Every JPA entity extends from `BaseEntity` and inherit `id` and `version` attributes of `BaseEntity`.

What is the best way here to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `BaseEntity`?  Every subclass of `BaseEntity` will inherit `equals()` and `hashCode()` behaviour form `BaseEntity`.

I want to do something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (other instanceof this.getClass()){ //this.getClass() gives class object but instanceof operator expect ClassType; so it does not work
            return this.id == ((BaseEntity)other).id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But `instanceof` operator needs classtype and not class object; that is:

- `if(other instanceof BaseEntity)`

  this will work as BaseEntity is classType here
- `if(other instanceof this.getClass)`

  this will not work because `this.getClass()` returns class object of `this` object

Comment: Just as a note, the JPA spec doesn't require entities to provide particular handling for hashCode/equals and use of DataNucleus as a JPA implementation doesn't require anything of that form. Obviously some others (e.g Hibernate?) may impose that on you

Comment: @DataNucleus Could you please show a reference pointing out that Hibernate does impose anything on you regarding `equals()/hashCode()` (hint: Hibernate itself does **not** call `equals()` and `hashCode()` on an entity object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
if (this.getClass().isInstance(other)) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928191/what-is-the-correct-way-of-overriding-hashcode-and-equals-methods-of-persis