# Grails findAll not finding values in a set

Tags: grails

I've got a domain called Planning that has a hasMany of another domain called Employee included in it. I'm trying to do a findAll of these plannings where the plannings contain a particular employee and I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to do it like so, my print statements do print the `contains` as true

```
plannings = plannings.findAll{planning->
  if(employee) {
    log.info("find plannings with employee ${employee} ${planning.employees.contains(employee)}")
    planning.employees.contains(employee)
  }
}
```

I'm not doing this as a Hibernate query as this broke the application in another weird way. This code is executed in a `for each` and for whatever reason that causes some weird behavior with Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The closure must return a `boolean` value - see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)

This should work (not tested):

```
 plannings = plannings.findAll{planning-> planning.employees?.contains(employee)}
```

BTW: I wouldn't assign the filtered list to the origin `plannings` list. Extract a a new  expressive variable like `planingsOfEmployee` or something similar.

Comment: `findAll` does not have to return a `boolean`, whatever it returns will be converted to a boolean using Groovy's truthiness rules https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-tell-groovy-truth.html

Comment: That still returns an empty list

Comment: @Rodin10: `contains` will use `equals` method of the `Employee` class (I guessed the class name), in case `equals` is not overwritten, object identity will be used. Are you sure, that your `employee` will match?

@Dónal: Good point! Thanks for pointing out my sloppy formulation.

Comment: My log.info line says so, I'll try comparing id's thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Rodin10: Make sure not to change the Id while the `employee` is in a Set - just mentioned it - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847272/equals-and-hashcode-when-storing-in-a-set-in-hibernate

Comment: I've changed it into `if(employee){
                        planning.employees*.id.contains(employee.id)
                    }` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I cannot help anymore, you have to provide more code. I suggest, that you write propper unit tests. Create `employees`, `plannings`  and use the debugger to check the object.

Answer (score 1):

Without more relevant details around your problem (what's the weird behavior? log traces? hibernate mappings?, etc.) all we can do is to speculate; and if I have to do so, I would say that most likely:

1. The `employee` object you are using for comparison is a detached one.
2. The `employee` object does not override meaningfully `equals` and `hashCode`
3. You use using this [detached](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview) `employee` to do comparisons against against [persisted](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview) `employees` (using `planning.employees.contains(employee)`) found inside `planning`

Under these circumstances the comparisons will never be true even when they may represent the same objects. If this is your case, you must either:

1. Use a persisted `employee` object to do the comparisons.
2. Or, [implement `equals` and `hashCode`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html) semantically meaningful for `Employee`

Hope this helps.